# AngularJS: $cookies.remove is not a function

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I am getting the error - "$cookies.remove is not a function" - when trying to clear the cookies in my angular application. As far as I can see I am following what the angular docs says, and also what has been said on this forum to remove cookies.

Here is my service which handles this,

```
app.service('authService', function ($cookies) {

    this.SetUsername = function (username) {
        $cookies.username = username;
    }

    this.GetUsername = function () {
        return $cookies.username;
    }

    this.clearCookie = function(){
        $cookies.remove("username");

    }

});
```

The get and set functions both work fine, it's just when actually trying to remove the cookie when calling the clear cookie function that i'm getting this issue.

Comment: console.log($cookies) ? is there .remove method?

Comment: Did you install angular-cookies? And did you add ngCookies to the dependencies of your app module? Use `console.dir($cookies);` to get the content of the object. Is a remove function defined? You have to open the console of you browser (F12?) to see to output.

Comment: Did you include angular-cookies.js? https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/

Comment: When i type that in console it says that $cookies is not defined, but I don't know how that can be the case since I am using it fine for storing values and it is not throwing errors? It is added within my module. and it is included correctly. I have managed to get this working by using delete $cookies["username"] but I'm not sure why this works and the other method does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, which version of Angular.js are you using? To me it seems that you're using 1.3.x which means that $cookies actually comes from the ngCookies plugin. In that case, $cookies is nothing more than a simple object where writing to creates a new cookie value. To directly quote **from the 1.3.x ngCookie** docs:

> Only a simple Object is exposed and by adding or removing properties
>   to/from this object, new cookies are created/deleted at the end of
>   current $eval. The object's properties can only be strings.
>
> Requires the ngCookies module to be installed.

In case you are using 1.4.x and up your implementation would actually be correct.

Comment: Hi, I am using v1.3.15 of angular. I thought the purpose of the .remove would be to get rid of a property in the cookie. As I said in the response above, I managed to get this working by using 'delete $cookies["username"];' instead

Comment: You're correct with your assumption but the .remove method is only available in 1.4.x and up. The API docs from angular make this sometimes hard to realise, but you have an API Version selector in the documentation in the upper left side. If you select 1.3 it will show up.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I should have realised you meant that from your initial post. I'll pay closer attention to the version of angular listed when I'm reading the docs in future.

Answer (score 0):

Include angular cookies file in your page.

Angular cookies file:-

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this while logout it will clear all cookies at a time

```
app.controller('controllername', function ($cookies) {
    $cookies.remove();})
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation.